# Configuring Gerrit to use LDAP

Tags: java, active-directory, gerrit

I'm trying to get gerrit setup using ldap.   My gerrit ldap config is as follows:

```
[ldap]
    server = ldap://foobar.local
    username = foobar\\gstralko
    password = mypassword
    accountBase = dc=foobar,dc=local
    groupBase = dc=foobar,dc=local
```

When I start up gerrit via:

```
java -jar /home/glassfish/gerrit-2.8.3.war init -d gerrit
```

I get the following errors in the logs:

> [2015-04-02 18:19:07,491] ERROR com.google.gerrit.server.auth.ldap.LdapRealm :        Cannot query LDAP to authenticate user
>   javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49 - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903AA, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 775, v1772]
>       at com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3067)

I know that ldap user is setup correctly because I can do the following with ldapsearch:

```
ldapsearch -h foobar.local -x -LLL -b "dc=foobar,dc=local" -D 'foobar\gstralko' -W
```

And that works.  So I'm wondering what am I missing in my gerrit.config file.

Thanks,

Comment: This looks like an ADS system and the error indicates an issue with the LDAP authetnication. Try `username = gstralko@yourd-ads-domain` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect Java's *configuration file parser* is tripping you with the password parameter,
so **look-out for any '`\`' characters** and **wrap the password in quotation-marks**,
like so:

```
...
password = "mypassword"
...
```

See this Gerrit documentation, for example:

> ...
>     The configuration file parser eats one level of backslashes,
>     so the character class \s requires \\s in the configuration file.
>     The parser also terminates the line at the first #,
>     so a match expression containing # must be wrapped in double quotes.

( from https://review.openstack.org/Documentation/config-gerrit.html#_file_code_etc_gerrit_config_code )